# Combinations, Expected Values and Random Variables

Tags: combinatorics, random-variables

A community consists of $100$ married couples ($200$ people). If during a given year, $50$ of the members of the community die, what is the expected number of marriages that remain intact?

Assume that the set of people who die is equally likely to be any of the ${200 \choose 50}$ groups of size $50$

**Hint:** For $i = 1, ..., 100$ let $X_i$ $=$$\{1$, if neither member of couple $i$ dies; and $0$, otherwise$\}$

It's a question from "Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists" by Sheldon Ross ... and I have no idea how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please check the edit. what is $200 C 50$; please review accordingly

Comment: Likely that $200C50 = { 200 \choose 50}$, esp for those who don't know how to write binomial coefficients in Latex.

Comment: Yup, my apologies. I'm not well versed enough in Latex. Calvin is right with the formatting of the "200 choose 50"

Comment: Could someone elaborate on how the combinatorics works in this question, because that's my first stumbling block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the linearity of expectation. Let $X$ be the rv of the number of couples that survive. Then $$X = \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i.$$

Thus,

$$E[X] = E[\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{100} E[X_i] = 100 E[X_1]. $$